# How to create an array data type in numpy using np.dtype or something similar?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, typing

so I have 4D ndarray where each element is an 8x8 numpy array with datatype np.int8. I want to use `tobytes()` to convert it to a bitstring and then `frombuffer()` to convert it back to its original state. How can I create a datatype `dt` such that `np.frombuffer(bits, dtype=dt)` gives me my original ndarray back after it is reshaped? Following the documentation here

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype

I've tried numerous things like `dt = np.dtype([('block', np.int8, (8x8))])` but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: is this really just a 6D array where each element is of type `np.int8`?.  So the shape of the array is `(N1, N2, N3, N4, 8, 8)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is really a 6D array where each element is an np.int8, you can do this like this:

```py
arr = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 8)).astype(np.int8)
print(arr.shape)
print(arr.dtype)
arr_bytes = arr.tobytes()
arr_reborn = np.frombuffer(arr_bytes, dtype=np.int8).reshape(arr.shape)
print(np.all(arr == arr_reborn))
```

prints

```
>>> (2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 8)
>>> int8
>>> True
```